# How to Pass Jsf Bean variable value to Jquery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have this java script code which is call on page page by jquery

```
 <script> 
  function initReportExplr() {
    alert(jQuery('#inputValues').val());

  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    initReportExplr();
  });
  </script>
```

and this is component i am using

```
<h:inputText id="inputValues" value="#{reportsBean.birtServerInformation}"/>
```

and inside get method i am initializing variable

```
public String getBirtServerInformation() {
        StringBuilder birtInfo = new StringBuilder();
        birtInfo.append(Constants.BIRT_SERVER_URL);
        birtInfo.append(",");
        birtInfo.append(Constants.BIRT_SERVER_PORT);
        birtInfo.append(",");
        birtInfo.append(Constants.BIRT_USER_NAME);
        birtInfo.append(",");
        birtInfo.append(Constants.BIRT_PASSWORD);
        birtServerInformation = birtInfo.toString();
        return birtServerInformation;
    }
```

But i am getting `undefined` when trying to print the value by this code  `alert(jQuery('#inputValues').val());`

Comment: What do you see when you do only `jQuery('#inputValues')`? And don't use `alert()` for debugging, use `console.log()` and see logs in `F12` console. If your `<h:inputText>` is inside `<h:form>` then id contains also naming container id. Use inspect on this field and check client ID, then it should work.

Comment: @Geinmachi I am getting `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: reportsForm1` tried this code        `jQuery('#contentform:reportsForm1:inputValues') ;`

Comment: You have to escape `:` with \\, so `jQuery('#contentform\\:reportsForm1\\:inputValues').val()`

Comment: @Geinmachi now i tried with this  ` var myArray  = document.getElementById("contentform:reportsForm1:inputValues").value;` this is giving proper values

Comment: Look my previous comment

Comment: @Geinmachi  That is giving same exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91023/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-geinmachi).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **@Geinmachi** one solution of this by jquery is

```
jQuery('#contentform\\:reportsForm1\\:inputValues').val();
```

and another way through JavaScript is

```
document.getElementById("contentform:reportsForm1:inputValues").value;
```